# How to match time in R, ignoring seconds? (unexpected behavior of match/trunc)

Tags: r, time, match, lubridate

I have a list of timestamps -- one every minute plus a few seconds. Now I want to use R to find a reference time in that list, considering only at date+hours+minutes while ignoring the seconds.

```
library(lubridate)
data <- c(
  "2016-10-09T23:05:01",
  "2016-10-09T23:06:01",
  "2016-10-09T23:07:01",
  "2016-10-09T23:08:01",
  "2016-10-09T23:10:10",
  "2016-10-09T23:11:01",
  "2016-10-09T23:12:01",
  "2016-10-09T23:13:04",
  "2016-10-09T23:14:02",
  "2016-10-09T23:15:03",
  "2016-10-09T23:16:10"
  )
dataParsed <- ymd_hms(data[])
refTime <- ymd_hms("2016-10-09T23:15:00")
```

I tried to use a combination of `trunc(..., "mins")` and `match()` to find the index of the wanted time. However, that produces some unexpected results:

The following should find the index for entry at "2016-10-09T23:15:03", but instead results in `idx==NA_integer`.

```
idx <- match(trunc(refTime,"mins"), trunc(dataParsed,"mins"))
```

Strangely enough, the following (with cutting the input to 10 timestamps) finds the searched time at `idx==9`.

```
idx <- match(trunc(refTime,"mins"), trunc(tail(dataParsed,10),"mins"))
```

Apparently, I made some mistake or have some wrong assumptions about what `trunc(..., "mins")` and `match()` do.

*Version info*
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running on Win10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the error occurs is because your times are stored as `POSIXlt` objects, and (for some reason) `match` isn't working.

You can:

1. Convert to `POSIXct` objects
2. Use `pmatch` or `which`.

### Using `POSIXct`

The difference is that `POSIXlt` is a *list* and `POSIXct` is a *number*.

```
idx <- match(as.POSIXct(trunc(refTime,"mins")), as.POSIXct(trunc(dataParsed,"mins")))
#> [1] 10
```

### Using `pmatch` or `which`

You can either use `pmatch` instead of `match`, or you can use `which` with an equality test.

```
pmatch(trunc(refTime,"mins"), trunc(dataParsed,"mins"))
#> [1] 10
```

Or `which`:

```
which(trunc(dataParsed,"mins") == trunc(refTime,"mins"))
#> [1] 10
```

Comment: I prefer the solutions with `pmatch` and `which`, since they do not require explicit conversion steps and are easier to read in source code.

Comment: IMO, `which` is probably the most "natural" for you, given your code (i.e. most clearly communicates the intent).

Comment: Yes, agree. `which` makes the intent really obvious. However, one needs into account that it might return a list, if there are multiple matching values.

Comment: True: you could force the first with `which(trunc(dataParsed,"mins") == trunc(refTime,"mins"))[[1]]` or handle separately.